# A problem regarding infinitives

Tags: infinitives

I was doing an exercise and I had to join two sentences using an infinitive.

The pair of sentences was--

> I have no aptitude for business. I must speak it out frankly.

The answer was--

> To speak out frankly, I have no aptitude for business.

My doubt is--

In the above sentence is ***to speak*** same as ***speaking*** or does it mean something else?

Comment: No native speaker would use "speak out" in either of those sentences.

Comment: Have you looked up, or asked your teacher, what an infinitive is?

Comment: 1: *I have no aptitude for business. I am speaking frankly* - not particularly idiomatic as two sentences. 2: *Frankly [speaking], I have no aptitude for business* - perfectly natural (we wouldn't usually bother including *speaking* at all, but it could come before or after the adverb). 3: *To be frank, I have no...* - again, perfectly natural. 4: *To speak frankly,...* - a bit stilted / circumlocutious.

Comment: @Fumblefingers The sentence is from wren and martin.